# How to get the child name when I click the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many search result like this:

```
<div id="product-button">
    <p id="product-id">id</p>
    <p id="product-name">name</p>
</div>
<div id="product-button">
    <p id="product-id">id</p>
    <p id="product-name">name</p>
</div>

etc etc
```

I need to get the text of the name and id of product that I click

my shut but print `<empty string>` in the console:`

```
$(document).on('click', '#product-button', function(){

  console.log($(this).closest('#product-button').children('#product-name').text());

});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your DOM has a major problem: ids must be unique. Consider using class if you have multiple version of the same thing before trying to proceed any further.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you, where ids must be unique?

Comment: Everywhere. You can only have one element with `id=something` in the entire document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of an element has to be unique. Replace them with classes.

```
<div class="product-button">
    <p class="product-id">id_1</p>
    <p class="product-name">name_1</p>
</div>
<div class="product-button">
    <p class="product-id">id_2</p>
    <p class="product-name">name_2</p>
</div>
```

$(this) is ('#product-button') so no need for it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.product-button', function(){

  console.log($(this).children('.product-name').text());

});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.product-button', function(){

  console.log(`${$(this).children('.product-name').text()} ${$(this).children('.product-id').text()}`);

});
```

```html
<div class="product-button">
    <p class="product-id">id_1</p>
    <p class="product-name">name_1</p>
</div>
<div class="product-button">
    <p class="product-id">id_2</p>
    <p class="product-name">name_2</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: also, get <empty string>!

Comment: Should this `$(document).on('click', '#product-button', function(){` then be this `$(document).on('click', '.product-button', function(){`?

Comment: Yeah, sure I tried both and still get <empty string>!

Comment: you got me wrong I need when I click on the parent which is (product-button) give me the children ( name, id )

Comment: @ahmed added the name and id